# Trouble assigning value by key in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
dictionary_list = [{"id":""},{"id":""}]
```

EDIT: since the intention is to allow a variable number of elements in the list, the list is actually built in this fashion:

```
shelves = 2
book = {"id":""}
dictionary_list = []
for counter in range(shelves):
    dictionary_list.append(book)
```

EDIT: I've also tried the following approach, suggested by the community:

```
shelves = 2
book = {"id":""}
dictionary_list = [book for i in range(shelves)]
```

I'm trying to assign the first element's "id" to "apple" as follows:

```
dictionary_list[0]["id"] = "apple"
```

The result:

```
print dictionary_list
>> [{"id":"apple"},{"id":"apple"}]
```

Of course, when I then assign `"orange"` to `dictionary_list[1]["id"]`, both id's are changed to orange.

What's going on here?  Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you've initiated your dictionary like this:

```
dictionary_list = [{"id":""}]*2
```

or similar. This is actually two references to the same dictionary, so when you change the value of one dictionary's `id` key, both are changed. This can be checked by using [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

```
>>> id(dictionary_list[0])
3055225778896
>>> id(dictionary_list[1])
3055225778896
```

You can fix this by initiating the dictionary like so:

```
dictionary_list = [{"id":""} for i in range(2)]
```

EDIT:

Given the new code:

```
shelves = 2
book = {"id":""}
dictionary_list = []
for counter in range(shelves):
    dictionary_list.append(book)
```

We can see that the same reference of `book` is appended to `dictionary_list` each time the for-loop runs. We could change this to work as follows:

```
shelves = 2
dictionary_list = []
for counter in range(shelves):
    dictionary_list.append({"id":""})
```

Or:

```
shelves = 2
book = {"id":""}
dictionary_list = []
for counter in range(shelves):
    dictionary_list.append(book.copy())
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `id()`, but I tried defining my dictionary in a few ways now, including the one I added to my original question as well as the one you described.  I verified with `id()` that both methods create two dictionaries with the same ids.  How unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the same book object multiple times. You need to either create the dict object every time inside the loop or append `book.copy()` to the list.

Like this

```py
for counter in range(shelves):
    dictionary_list.append(book.copy())
```

Or like this

```
dictionary_list = [{"id":""} for counter in range(shelves)]
```